# unresolved import из собственных пакетов VSCode python 3.8

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Всем привет!
Имеется проект структуры:

```
|Root_folder/
   |--.vscode/
      |--settings.json
   |--Pack/
      |--__init__.py
      |--a.py
      |--b.py
|main.py
```

В main.py если импортировать любые модули и пакеты проблем нет.
Если импортировать модуль b в модуле a, то скрипт нормально работает, однако VSCode подчеркивает строку

```
#a.py
import b
```

с ошибкой unresolved import. Соответственно не работает проверка и автодополнение кода. То есть для всех модулей в пакетах VSCode не видит импорта, хотя скрипты нормально работают. Как редактировать код модулей пакетов, не открывая их по-отдельности?

Система Win10, VSCode 1.41, Python 3.8

Comment: в `a.py` попробуйте `from Pack import b`, т.е. `b` входит в пакет `Pack`

Answer (score 2):

при импорте по факту указывается путь к файлу для импортирования. в данном случае модули `a` и `b` находятся в пакете (директории) `Pack`. Таким образом если корневая директория прокета `Root_folder`, то импортировать модуль `b` и/или `a` можно по абсолютному пути `Pack.a` или `Pack.b`

```
from Pack import a
```

Если корневая директория станет `Pack`, то вы сможете импортировать модули `a` и `b` напрямую.

Например перейдите в директорию `Pack`, напишите в файле `b.py`

```
import a
```

И выполните `Root_folder/Pack$ python b.py`

Это будет работать, однако IDE будет подчеркивать этот импорт как недействительный, так как будет считать корневой директорией директорию уровнем выше (в данном случае), что указано в настройках проекта.

Именно поэтому IDE вам и указывает на недействительный импорт, так как если коневая директория проекта `Root_folder`, а вы импортируете модуль `a` в `b.py` через

```
import a
```

то ищите файл `a.py` в директории `Root_folder`.

Python предоставляет 2 возможности импорта, первый - абсолютный импорт был описан выше мной и в коментарии. Второй - относительный импорт.

```
#b.py
from . import a
```

таким образом вы указываете через точку что ищите в текущем каталоге, или 2 точки если хотите подняться на уровень выше. В целом работает это так же как и с путями (потому что этим и является).

Также можно с точкой использовать и имена пакетов или модулей

```
from .a import *
```

Такой способ импорта внутри пакета, дает возможность не менять пути импорта при переименовании пакета.

Все пути где пайтон ищет пути для импорта описаны в sys.path, модифицируя который можно импортировать что угодно, откуда угодно ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Если все работает, а `VSCode` подчеркивает импорты и использование сущностей с этих импортов, то можно сконфигурировать пути откуда у вас импртируются ваши модули, т.к. изначально прописан только корень для модулей (это может быть как виртуальное пространство, так и без него). Для этого в папке `.vscode` открываем файл `settings.json` и добавляем там такую строку:

```json
{
    ....,
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./Pack"]
}
```

Проверено на следующей системе: `Win10(x64, pro), VSCode - v1.56, Python - 3.8.6`